# Is there somewhere to view the source code for Google Sheets built-in functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know that you can't use the Google Sheets built-in functions in custom functions written in Google Apps Script, but I would assume that the built-in functions were written in a similar—if not the same—language. As such, it would be useful to see how they were written both for learning purposes and to help add analogs to custom functions.

I've been trying to find somewhere that provides this, but my searches only lead to the Google Sheets function list, offering a useless (for this) description, and several instances of people asking why they can't use the built-in functions in GAS.

Comment: If the function is written in client side js, it should be visible in the browser-view source code. But it will be obfuscated/minified. If it is server side, it won't be accessible. You can try creating a issue in issuetracker for direct support from Google. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Many of the built in functions are simply wrappers for the javascript Math library, abs(), sin(), exp(), etc..  What function are you interested in.? There is probably someone who has tried to reverse engineer it on google search.

Comment: @TheMaster I hadn't thought about looking at a spreadsheet with DevTools (if that's what you mean). I think I found the area where the formulas are in the js, but it's definitely obfuscated. Oh well.

Comment: @TheWizEd I don't really have any function that I'm specifically interested in. I just wanted to see how they look. I like to take things apart and see how they work. I'm starting to learn to program and think seeing examples of things I understand the end result of would be useful.